# Why are there multiple ways to say hello in Japanese and how would I use them?

Tags: meaning, greetings

I have been learning basic sentences in Japanese, but I want to know what to use when I meet somebody and why. the three I know are:

- Yoroshiku onegaishimasu.
- Konnichiwa.
- Hajimemashite.

What would I use if I met someone for the first time?

Comment: I think any language is going to have many different greetings that are used like "hello," but I wouldn't put yoroshiku onegaishimasu or hajimemashite as equivalent to "hello."

Comment: You should have the answer in any textbook on Japanese conversation. You can use all of them *Konnichiwa. Hajimemashite. Yoroshiku onegaisimasu*.

Comment: oooh. I wasn't sure. I dont often listen to much in japanese other than anime, and I have never really been sure. thank you!